# Why doesn't nested if-statement's console.log method work?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I can't use functions to clear the following exercice and would really like to know why both methods `console.log` don't work?

```js
var answer;

while (true) 
{
 alert("Answer using \"yes\" or \"no\"");
    answer = prompt("Welcome to the port!\nDo you want to get on board?").toLowerCase();
 if (answer === "yes"){
  alert("Hi!");
  
  var answer2 = prompt("Have you ever sailed?").toLowerCase();
  while((answer2 != "yes") && (answer2 != "no") && (answer2 != null))
  {
   
   answer2 = prompt("Have your ever sailed?").toLowerCase();
   if (answer2 === "yes"){
   console.log("Welcome on board!");
   }
   else if (answer2 === "no"){
   console.log("goodbye.");
   }
   
  }
  break; 
 
 }
 else if (answer === "no"){
  alert("Bye!");
    break;
 }
}
```

Comment: They do work, how are you exactly trying?

Comment: For which input do you expeect them to work ? If you answer "yes" then "aaaaa" then ("yes" or "no"), they do work, as your code tells.

Comment: `while((answer2 != "yes") && (answer2 != "no") && (answer2 != null))` this condition will never run if the answer is either yes or no. Because of the condition

Comment: Make `answer2 = prompt("Have your ever sailed?").toLowerCase();` the only line inside the while loop by moving the rest below it, remove `break;` and it will work as expected. (your code requires answering the sailed question with something invalid first, or the execution never enters the inner while loop)

Comment: @ChrisG what do you mean by moving the rest below it? Can you edit the code? I've deleted `var answer2 = prompt("Have you ever sailed?").toLowerCase();` but I feel like you mean something different.

Comment: Inside your inner while loop is a bunch of lines. Keep the one starting with `answer2 = ...`, but cut the rest and paste them below (after) the loop.

Comment: You can also use `do { answer = prompt(...); } while (answer != "yes" && answer != "no");`, that way you don't need two prompt lines for the same question.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChrisG. Why does the if- and else if-statement have to be outside the second while-loop? Could I use the same pattern and insert an answer3?

Comment: Like I said, to get something logged to the console, the execution has to enter the while loop first. This only happens if you enter something invalid when you are being asked about having sailed for the first time. With my changes, entering "yes" or "no" the first time will skip the while loop entirely, then check the answer against the condition for the console.log commands.

Comment: However, if you plan to add more questions to this, keeping nesting these loops is a bad idea. You need to write a custom function that handles a single question, then simply call it a bunch of times.

Comment: That was very clear and helpful. Thank you for that @ChrisG. I assume that that exercice was about nesting statements inside while-loops. I will try to rewrite it with a function.